# Comparing an inputted C-string to a file read C-string

Tags: c++, char, compare, cstring

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this isn't working. Here is my code for the function in questions:

```
int searchDisplay()
{
vector<Client> store;
char nameSearch[SIZE];
string input;
Client foo;
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
bool flag = false;

fstream customer("customer.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);


if (!customer)
{
    cout << "Error opening file. Program aborting." << endl;
    return 0;
}

while (!customer.eof())
{
    store.push_back(foo);

    customer.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&store[i]),
                sizeof (store[i]));
    i++;
}

cin.ignore();
cout << "User, please enter the full name of the client you wish to search for:        
             ";
getline(cin, input);

strcpy(nameSearch, input.c_str());

if (strcmp(nameSearch, store[0].name))
{
    cout << "FINALLY!" << endl << endl;
}

customer.close();

return 1;
enter code here
}
```

My issue is with the

`if (strcmp(nameSearch, store[0].name))
{ cout << "FINALLY!" << endl << endl; }`

It isn't comparing the `nameSearch` with the name in `store[0].name`.
I am using this method, however be aware that `if (nameSearch == store[0].name)` didn't work either.

If "Frank Palmasani" is stored in `nameSearch` through user input, and "Frank Palmasani" is stored in `store[0].name` through reading from the file, it still doesn't come back as `=` values.

I have tried using `cin` to get the input for `nameSearch` and that was of little luck as well.  I just cannot seem to get this to work.  I am not sure if it has anything to do with binary since I am using binary as my method of writing and reading.

I have little practice with c-strings, so I was wondering if there is something crucial I am leaving out of this program?

Thanks if you can help! This is literally the only thing standing between me and getting a move on with this project.

Answer (score 0):

ALRIGHT! GOT IT! Seems as though I missed where `strcmp()` returns `0` if true, `1` if false. So to go about this, I compared like this:

```
end = strcmp(nameSearch, store[0].name);
if (end == 0)
{
    cout << "They are equivalent." << endl;
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who runs into similar issues!